# Elasticsearch: поиск по нескольким полям. Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста как создать запрос для поиска нужного элемента по нескольким полям. К примеру:

```
        {
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "1",
    "_source": {
        "name": "Ivan",
        "age": "20",
    }
}

    {
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "users",
    "_id": "2",
    "_source": {
        "name": "Ivan",
        "age": "25",
    }
}
```

Мне нужно создать запрос типа: SELECT FROM users WHERE name="Ivan" AND age="25"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено, спасибо **Etki**

```
    QueryBuilder qb = boolQuery().must(termQuery("name", "Ivan")).must(termQuery("age", "25"));
    SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.getClient().prepareSearch(client.getIndex()).setTypes("users").setQuery(qb).setSize(1);
    SearchResponse response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

не отказывайтесь от заглядывания в [документацию](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), пока вы не поймете, как работает инструмент и где искать ответы, вы и не начнете его использовать

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": "Ivan"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "age": "25"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

дополнительно рекомендую прочитать секцию про анализаторы и terms **до** того, как начнете искать по строкам, если запрос будет состоять из нескольких слов (e.g. "John Doe"), вы будете удивлены результатом.

Comment: это я знаю. мне нужно сделать такой же запрос с использованием Java API

Comment: @PREDATORik там же абсолютно идентичный dsl. `QueryBuilders.boolQuery()`, `QueryBuilders.termQuery()`. если будет время, напишу полностью пример

Comment: буду очень благодарен